# MariaDB does not start after relocating directory

Tags: centos, mariadb

I am installing MariaDB 10.1 on Linux CentOS 7.0. The default datadir is in /var/lib/mysql where is only 2GB space. So I need to move it to the home directory where there is 200 GB space.

So I copied the mysql directory into /home. I made necessary changes in the config file, compared directory rights every thing is same. I have disabled SELinux so thats not the problem.

MariaDB does not start. When I checked in /var/log/messages, it says /usr/sbin/mysqld: C'ant change dir to '/home/mysql' (ErrCode: 13 Permission Denied")

To check my methodology, I repeated the above process and moved the datadir to /var/mysql. After making necessary changes in the config file, I got MariaDB to start.

So I can move the datadir to /var/mysql and it works. When I move the datadir to /home/mysql,  MariaDB gives an error and does not start.

When I checked the rights for the directory in /home, it is the same as in /var Is there anything special about the home directory. What am I missing.

Comment: Let's see `ls  -ld  /home  /home/mysql`

Comment: @RickJames. Sorry for the delay in replying.   
ls -ld /home     drwxr-xr-x 5 root root

Comment: ls -ld /home/mysql         drwxrwxrwx 5 mysql mysql

Comment: Could not solve this error. So I reinstalled CentOS, created a separate partition and moved mysql there. Works now.